# Sum of two variables from div

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, twig

I want to sum the two field automatically using javascript ,

After searching more about what I want exactly I found this example on table please how can I change it to work on divs

http://jsfiddle.net/gXdwb/3/

**Those are my fields**

```
<div> class="form-group">
    <label for="nbStudentA" >Number student A</label>
    <div> 
        {{ form_widget(form.nbStudentA, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for=" nbStudentB " >Number Student B</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      {{ form_widget(form.nbStudentB, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Sum" >Sum Students :</label>
    <div>
        <input  type="text" class="Sum"  name="total" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**update:**

what I have tried before is to sum the two variables using twig but it's done on the server side and what I want is the effectuate the sum just when the user enter the variables:

```
<div >
    <label>Sum </label>
    <div >
        {% set foo = form.nbStudentA + form.nbStudentB %}
       {{ foo }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see no values to sum?

Comment: {{ form_widget(form.nbStudentB, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }} and {{ form_widget(form.nbStudentB, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }} are two value entred by the user (twig)

Comment: It looks like you are using AngularJS. The `{{ ... }}` syntax shows it might. Your JS fiddle uses jQuery which is a totally different library. It looks like you are new to this code and just want us to fix it for you. Can you be more specific into what you have tried yourself, and what exactly you want help with? The JS fiddle is not applicable to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know exactly what you want but this does work.If you want from only div

```
<div id="std-1">1</div>
<div id="std-2">2</div>
<div>{{one + two}}</div>
</div>
 //scripts
 $scope.one=parseInt(document.getElementById('std-1').innerHTML);
 $scope.two=parseInt(document.getElementById('std-2').innerHTML);
```

or you don't mind input fields and making it dynamic

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app>
    <div class="std-1">
     Student one: <input ng-model="student.one " type="number"/>
    </div>
    <div class="std-2">
     Student two:  <input ng-model="student.two " type="number"/>
    </div>
    <div>Sum: {{student.one + student.two}}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app>  
<div id="first">
  <input ng-model="first"  placeholder="First number"  type="text" />
 </div> 
 <div id="second">
  <input ng-model="second" placeholder="Second number" type="text" />
 </div>
  <h1> Sum: {{first--second}} </h1>
</div>
```