# Calculate the sum of two integers on client side

Tags: symfony, sum, twig

I have to sum two integer in real time when the user enter value1 and value2 without pressing any button.

I have tring to use twig but it’s server side (after submitting).
Please how can I calculate the sum?

I have done some search I have found the same question but the answer is to use angular and I dont know how to use angular with twig.

similar question :[Sum of two variables from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237456/sum-of-two-variables-from-div)

```
<div>


<div> 
        {{ form_widget(form.value1) }} 
</div>


<div> 

      {{ form_widget(form.value2) }} 
</div>

<div> 

   {{ form.value1+ form.value2 }}
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Just use javascript then?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a field id using `{{ form.value1.vars.id }}`.

So you can imagine something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#{{ form.value1.vars.id|e('js') }}, #{{ form.value2.vars.id|e('js') }}').keyup(function() {
     alert($('#{{ form.value1.vars.id|e('js') }}').val() + $('#{{ form.value2.vars.id|e('js') }}').val());
  });  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how can I put the result in a html element not in alert box?

Comment: you replace `alert(...)` by `$('#id-of-element').html(...)` - This is the basics of jquery, I advise you to follow some tutorials.

Comment: thank you ,yes sure I should learn some jquery , but it's a sudden work!